# omnistudio - navigate action buttons for multiple datatable rows

Tags: lightning-web-components, omnistudio, omniscript, data-raptor

I have a datatable in a flexcard where I show Name and Status from the IndividualApplication object.

For each row on the datatable I want to put a navigate action button that will launch an OmniScript with that specific IndividualApplication the button is associated to's Id as the recordId.

I've been able to add a single button on the flexcard but can't seem to figure out how to create one for each specific record in the datatable and have the recordId be associated properly. Any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is actually going to be to change how you are building it. What I mean is that I would recommend making a parent flexcard and a child flexcard. The child flexcard would be a row of data plus the custom button. You would have the child flexcard repeating within the parent. That would allow you to make the custom button you are looking for in each line that could launch the OmniScript. Another potentially much more complex option would be to add JS to create the buttons on the DOM using the datatable data. I do not necessarily recommend that option unless you are already very good at JS but wanted to mention it.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. We look forward to seeing more great content in the future!